# Types of firewalls to implement to reduce DoS attacks in POS systems

Tags: firewalls, denial-of-service

Would you need an internal, external and a host-resident firewall for each POS client?

Comment: Sorry I am still new to the subject. I want prevent or reduce the risk of say a Smurf Attack maybe by filtering out spoofing packets.

Comment: Ok, so not DDoS, but classic DoS threats. Firewalls can help with that if they have those inspection features. Where to place them depends entirely on the network architecture and where those threats will be coming from. Can you explain more about the architecture?

Comment: It is a small point of sale network. Just one server and four client workstations with the POS application on them.

Comment: Ok, and where are the DoS threats coming from? (You put protections in place in the vector of t he threat)

Comment: Say externally from a malicious party wanting to prevent payments from occuring

Comment: Please include the description of your network architecture within your initial question. It’s better to sve disproportionate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple areas of concern with DOS/DDOS attacks. If they are external they can fill up the "pipe" in your ISP before they ever reach you. That means that nothing on the inside (internal firewalls, layer 7, blackholes) will prevent packet loss before you even are reached. In order to mitigate this you need to contact your ISP and they will have protections (Kona being Akamai's; there are others).

Internally, a layer 7 firewall should have protections against this. Most layer 7's work with "DPI" and "stateful" detection which means that if you're getting a packet that doesn't make sense for the communication flow, it will be blocked. It will also cut connections for slow loris and other common attacks.

How does your small subnet use the internet? What are you required to allow in? Can you set this up in "proxy half open" which means that anything is allowed out to start a connection, but all incoming connection requests are blocked? That alone should solve this problem so long as the packet flood isn't more than your ISP "pipeline."